# Tengo que hacer una aplicacion para escritorio de un sistema administrativo usando net con C# con Winform o WPF usando Xaml

Tags: c#, windows-forms, xaml

mi sistema anterior esta realizado en visual basic 6.

Mi consulta es si uso Winform en net con C# o codigo Xaml con WPF,
en cuanto a rendimiento vb6 funcionaba en cualquier pc y era rapido el programa.

veo que net lleva muchos recursos para levantar un programa, a veces lerdo la primera vez
al ejecutarlos, es otra velocidad y recursos que se necesitan por supuesto pero necesito migrar a un nuevo lenguaje.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: WPF apareció el 2006, si corría en esos computadores yo no me preocuparía mucho del rendimiento en comparación a winforms

Answer (score 0):

Creo que xaml ofrece muchas más opctiones que windows forms. Sobre todo en tema de apariencia. Pero si quieres algo sencillo y rapido ves a winforms.